# I'm having issues running a .exe for another program within my the program I'm working on right now

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to run another .exe within a program I'm creating right now, however each time I try I get this error: \Users\*****\Downloads\pdcurs34.zip No such file or directory

Here's some basic information about what I'm using the ide I'm using is codeblocks, the language is c++, and the OS is Windows 7. If I've missed anything please let me know so I can update quickly.

And here's the block of code that I typed up, note I got this code from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oP75mlISPqQ#t=688 and if you watch a bit further into the tutorial you'll notice that the program within works the way it was intended to. If it matters, I've saved the program in my C drive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void launchSuperHexagon(string fileName){
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", fileName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}

int main()
{
    launchSuperHexagon("mspaint");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your program.

Comment: I know, however it produces an error whenever I run it, I know it's not the code, but I think it's because of either codeblocks, mingw, or path found in environmental variables. I tried most of the solutions I found online, but none of them worked. For example, I've reinstalled mingw and codeblocks, that didn't work, and I've added mingw to path, that didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks for all who help :3

Comment: Be sure you are running what you've compiled. I cant see how this file is related to your program. maybe try to run some simple program and see if the problem continues.

Comment: I've just created a quick hello world program, when I built and ran it it failed to build... Any ideas?

Comment: I have never gotten codeblocks to work on windows. Take [Qt-Creator](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) (can be used independently of Qt) or [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx).

Comment: @user1908245 what it's mean failed to build? you've got an error?